# PyGTK custom signals send a list as parameter

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to add a custom signal to a class -

```
class TaskBrowser(gobject.GObject):
    __list_signal__ = (gobject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, gobject.TYPE_NONE, (<List datatype>,))
    __gsignals__ = {'tasks-deleted': __list_signal__}

    ...

    def on_delete_tasks(self, widget=None, tid=None):
        ...
        gobject.idle_add(self.emit, "tasks-deleted", deleted_tasks) #deleted_tasks is of type 'list'
        ...

    ...
```

In the `__gsignals__` dict, when I state `list` as parameter type, I get the following error traceback -

```
File "/home/manhattan/GTG/Hamster_in_hands/GTG/gtk/browser/browser.py", line 61, in <module>
  class TaskBrowser(gobject.GObject):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gobject/__init__.py", line 60, in __init__
  cls._type_register(cls.__dict__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gobject/__init__.py", line 115, in _type_register
  type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
  could not get typecode from object
```

I saw the list of [possible parameter types](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygobject-reference/gobject-constants.html), and there's no type for `list`

Is there a way I can pass a list as a signal parameter ?

Comment: It works ! using either `object` or `gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT`.
Please can you explain why ?

Comment: You can use any Python object when specifying TYPE_PYOBJECT. I guess it essentially stands for 'anything'. The drawback is lack of type safety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C library needs to know the C type of the parameters, for Gtk, Gdk, Gio and GLib objects the types in the wrappers will work as they mirror the C types in the Gtk and family libraries.

However, for any other type you need to pass either `object` or `gobject.TYPE_PYOBJECT`. What that means is that the on the C side a "python object" **type** is passed. Every object accessible from a python script is of that type, that pretty much means anything you can pass through your python script will fit an `object` parameter.

That also means, of course, that this feature doesn't work in python! Python relies on *duck typing*, that means we figure out if an object is of a type when we do stuff with it and it works. Passing the type of the parameter works for C as a way to make sure the objects passed are of the type the program needs them to be, but in python *every object is of the same type in the C side* so this feature becomes completely useless on the python side.

But that doesn't means it is completely useless overall. For example, in python `int` is an `object`. But not in C. If you are using *property bindings*, which were coded in the C side of the Gtk library, you will want to specify the appropriate type as bindings of different property types don't work.

Using C side wrapped signal handlers with `object` parameter types is also bound not to work, since the C side needs a specific type to function.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I also learnt quite a few things apart from 'why do we use `object`' doubt

Answer (score 0):

In pygtk3 this error has been occured for me because `import gobject` directly.
and fixed this error by `from gi.repository import GObject`.
you can see details in this [link](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/python-hackers-list/2011-August/msg00005.html).